# MsAccess QueryDef.SQL different from actual query sql

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I export my msaccess queries sql code for source versioning. I have been doing this for a while, but just now noticed an inconsistency. The exported sql code was different from the code I would get from navigating to the SQL view in Design Mode. It would be an older version. My export code boils down to this:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim qr As QueryDef
Dim arq_out As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
arq_out = FreeFile
arq_name = "Querydefs.sql"

Open destPath & arq_name For Output As arq_out
For Each qr In db.QueryDefs
    If Not qr.Name Like "~TMP*" Then
        Print #arq_out, qr.Name
        Print #arq_out, qr.sql
        Print #arq_out, String(70, "-")
    End If
Next qr
```

The current database is one I had not used for more than a year.

You may understand better with this timeline:

1. Updated a few queries (long time ago). The update consisted of renaming some queries and then adjusting accordingly downstream.
2. Exported SQL query code with above VBA (today).
3. Noticed that a certain `queryA`'s sql was weirdly using its dependency's old name.
4. Opened `queryA`in design view and it showed the dependency's correct name. Different from what was exported. So I closed **without** saving.
5. Ran `Compact & Repair` before exporting again with the same VBA.
6. `queryA` had the correct code exported.
7. Noticed some `queryB` in the same database had a similar "obsolete" problem.
8. Same as 4, 5 and 6.

So it seems MsAccess stores it's SQL somewhere else and is feeding me an old or cached version. I do not even know if I regressed some relevant change due to this wrench in my workflow, as I use it ad-hoc for data analysis as a work limitation.

I tried querying the system tables to see if those held the correct SQL, but ran into the same issue. They would show me the old dependencies and be automatically updated after I opened the design view. I used the following sample query:

```
SELECT MSysQueries.Name1, MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysQueries INNER JOIN MSysObjects ON MSysQueries.ObjectId = MSysObjects.Id
WHERE (((MSysQueries.Name1)="Dependency_Old_Name"));
```

I would appreciate help to either: get the actual sql code from MsAccess or force MsAccess to update all `QueryDefs.SQL`.

Opening and closing the queries in design view would not be the preferred solution, as it sometimes introduces spurious `as Expr1`. But it may well be the solution if nothing else is possible.

Comment: Did you try to Compact & Repair for updating? Also the name may be different if you renamed the object when Object Navigator was in Custom view and objects were assigned to custom groups. In this case original object name remains the same, but appears an alias for selected custom group.

Comment: Yes, Sergey, I ran Compact & Repair many times. It does not seem to cause `QueryDef.SQL` to update. I do not use Custom View, only occasional filtering. In any case, I need to get whatever SQL I would get from navigating by hand, as the circunstances when the edit was done may not have been controled or known.